# The meaning of 'attend'

Tags: word-meaning

> Lecar and Franklin (1973) investigate hundreds of collisions occurring
>   in a period of only a few thousand years in the early history of the
>   asteroid belt, to understand the present configuration of this region
>   of the solar system. In another paper, entitled “Cometary Collisions
>   and Geological Periods,” Harold Urey (1973) investigates a range of
>   consequences, including the production of earthquakes and the heating
>   of the oceans, which might **attend** the collision with the Earth of
>   a comet of average mass of about 1018 grams. The Tunguska event of
>   1908, in which a Siberian forest was leveled, is often attributed to
>   the collision with the Earth of a small comet.
>
> *Broca's Brain: Reflections on the Romance of Science By Carl Sagan*

I looked up the dictionary, but can't figure out the meaning of '**attend**' here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [***attend***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attend):

> 4)  (transitive; often passive) to accompany or follow"   ⇒  ■ *a high temperature attended by a severe cough*"

or
[***attend***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/attend):

> 4) to accompany as a circumstance or result"   ⇒ *success attended his efforts*"

My choice with the closest meaning would be:

> ...including the production of earthquakes and the heating of the oceans, which might **accompany or follow** the collision with the Earth of a comet of average mass of about 1018 grams.

Comment: This sense of "attend" is slightly old-fashioned and formal, in this native speaker's opinion.  You don't hear it spoken too much, although you might find it in a book like Sagan's.

Answer (score 0):

See Oald, attend (verb) no. 4, meaning to happen at the same time as something. This use is relatively rare. You might replace  "which might attend" by "due to".
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attend?q=attend